# CMS breaks up after installing GUI Extension that uses CoreService (Web 8.5)

Tags: web8.5, gui-extensions, upgrade

We upgraded our environment from Web 8.1.1 to Web 8.5.
We have a few GUI Extensions that uses CoreService (2015) working in one environment. We made a clean install of 8.5 and tried to re-install the GUI Extension, but after we enable it, the CMS gets broken and we need to do an IISRESET.

In Chrome Console I can only see this:

[image]

> http://localhost/WebUI/Editors/Base/Views/Authentication/Authentication.aspx
>   failed to load within 10 seconds  Navigation.js:1

I've enabled Failed Trace Logs in IIS and the only Warning I got is this one:

[image]

I also tried to ping CoreService with WCF Test Client and got this:

[image]

The CMS shows while broken: The webpage at

```
http://localhost/WebUI/Editors/Base/Views/Authentication/Authentication.aspx might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
```

And sometimes:

The webpage at

```
http://localhost/WebUI/Editors/Base/Views/ProxyView/ProxyView.aspx?pagePath=~/../CME/Views/Welcome/Welcome.aspx might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
```

If I remove the extension from system.config it works again (after IISRESET).

I also set log level to DEBUG in system.config but nothing is logged.

Any idea?

Comment: It appears the UI extension is obviously breaking the CM Explorer, so you will need to at least provide more details about them. I suggest you **edit** your question and provide some details about the UI extension that breaks (focus on one, not two at the same time).

Comment: But that's the problem...I don't have logs (nothing is written to them) and if I try to attach to the process from Visual Studio my breakpoints are not hit (maybe this is occuring before). Any different idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally it was the override of Name property

The code had this

```
public override string Name
{
    get { return Name; }
}
```

Which worked in Web8! But seems now something is actually using it so it was recursively called.

using this

```
public override string Name
{
    get
    {
        Type itsMe = GetType();
        return string.Concat(itsMe.Namespace, ".", itsMe.Name);
    }
}
```

Made it work.